# htaccess and minus don't work in the url

Tags: .htaccess

When the url is `www.xxx.com/theproblem/is-here.html`. i want to get `is-here.html`, but with this rule....

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-\_A-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)?(?<!\.html)\b/?(([^/]+)\.html)?$ this.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3
```

...the returned value of param3 is `here.html`. That because param 2 get `is-`.

Why is this happening?

I want to achieve this goal:

```
www.xxx.com/theproblem/is-here.html. -> param1=theproblem | param2=is-here.html
www.xxx.com/theproblem/why-this/ -> param1=theproblem | param2=why-this
www.xxx.com/theproblem/why-this/is-here.html. -> param1=theproblem | param2=why-this | param3=is-here.html
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It's not maybe exactly what you want (at the level of the regex), but this is working :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.].html)$ this.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ this.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.].html)$ this.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
```